# Windows - Remove specific lines from a very large text file

Tags: windows, text-files, textedit

I have a very large text file (600mb), and I want to remove specific lines from within that file.

I know the line numbers I want to remove. Is there a really simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know how to use a scripting language, such as PHP or Python? Or do you need to do that from a text-editor? If so, which text editor?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do this. You have to read the entire file, make the modifications you need, and then re-write the file. You cannot delete from the middle of a file any other way.

As a minor optimisation, you only need to re-write the part of the file following the first modification. But you have to re-write the entirety after that. If your deleted lines are towards the end of the file, then this could be a significant optimisation.

For this reason, large text files are not the best storage format if you want to make such modifications. A database would lead to better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in C# with ease.
But I don't know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses - I have found a simple way of doing it in the Vim editor for windows.

Just by way of info, the file in question was a supplied .sql file for re-creating a mysql database so had no option but to manipulate it really.

Thanks again guys.

Comment: If you're posting an answer to your own question, would you at least detail *what* exactly you did to solve the problem?

Comment: OK, apologies. In Vim for windows, when you search for a text string (or go to a specific line) it will highlight everything between the new cursor location and the previous one, allowing you to simply delete the lines in question. I was able to delete the 4.8 million redundant lines from the text file in question in a couple of minutes.

Comment: You asked this question at the wrong site. This site is for programming problems, and hence the answers you got. But you wanted to modify just a single file once. And your solution was to use a text editor (any editor would do). You should have asked this question at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
$linesToRemove = 15,534,814,4632
$encoding = 'ASCII' # or 'UTF8', depending on what you need
Get-Content foo.sql |
  ForEach-Object { $i=0 } { $i++ } |
  Where-Object { $linesToRemove -notcontains $i }
```